# Dealing with token expiration in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Well we have a small node app that simulates an IoT device that we will install on a radiator and writes to the realtime database. The device will read/write on the node of the database that matches with its uid as the rules set below:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$userid":{
      ".read": "auth.uid === $userid",
      ".write": "auth.uid === $userid"     
    }
}
```

Our idea is that when it comes to production and before shipping them to sellers, the device will connect to a server and get a token generated with firebase-admin auth createCustomToken function. For this example we have manually generated a token with a fixed uid:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");   


var uid="F1FF00FF01";

admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
.then(function(customToken){
    console.log("CREATED: " + customToken);
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
});
```

The node app is as follows:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
var fs = require("fs");
const util = require('util');
var content = fs.readFileSync("device_data.json");
var jsonContent= JSON.parse(content);

var idRD=jsonContent.MACRD;
console.log("loaded: " + idRD);

var config = {<<Client API Config>>};
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


var token="<<The generated token with the admin app>>";
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error){
   var errorCode = error.code;
   var errorMessage = error.message;
   console.log("Error auth: " + error.code + " - " + error.message);
});


firebase.database().ref("/" + idRD).set(jsonContent,function(){console.log("SET OK");});
```

When we execute the app, all works fine.

Now when we let an hour pass and we execute again the app, the following error appears:

> Error auth: auth/invalid-custom-token - The custom token format is
>   incorrect. Please check the documentation.

We understand this is caused by the token expiration, and that the only way of preventing this is to keep the device connected to the database or sign in again with the token before expiration. But we have the problem that our idea is to ship the device with the token and weeks and months can pass before the device is sold and connect again to the database and at that moment the token will be invalid.

Is there any workaround to avoid this? We have been thinking of using simpleLogin instead but we don´t see the point of having every device having a fake email and a password to login.

**EDIT:**

Talking with one of our clients that has an iot solution based on firebase in which they have one token for each device and it has been the same token from 2015. When they make an API REST call, they used with something similar to this:

```
https://example.firebaseio.com/devices/1234567890ABCDEF/data.json?auth=eyJ0eXAi.OiJKV1.iLCJhbGciOi.JIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjIzO.Dk3NjkxODYsInY.OjAsImlhdCI6MT.0Mjk5Nzk4NiwiZCI6e.J1aWQiOiI.Iiwic2VyaWFsbnVt.mVyIjoiMzMzN.M0MzczMjMzND.wQTAwMjgwM.QxIiwiaW.iOiIxIn19.s-AtwzIH.WhVQWCIvdT8YHVa.NoG_KLO.wEBQF.n6mE
```

They don´t know how it was created because the server part was developed by another company, so they only were given the tokens. They only thing they know it´s that it never expires and each token identifies a unique user that has only permisions on that route on the database. ¿It´s this the way to go or it´s some firebase legacy compatibility that will be discarded?